# Launching an App when user click son toast using OnLaunched Event

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to send Launch a page when user clicks on Toast notification by overriding OnLaunchedEvent in App.xaml.

Here is the code to it.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
 string launchstring = args.Arguments;
            if (lauchstring=="InstructionSet"")
            {

              rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(InstructionSet));
            }
}
```

The code checks Arguments passed from Azure for "Instructonset" strign and launches that page.

Here is my Azure code

```
 push.wns.sendTileWideSmallImageAndText04(channel.uri, {
                     image1src: item.imageUrl,
                     text1: item.componentName,
                     text2:item.alarmType,
                     audiosrc:'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call', audioloop:'false'
                }, {
                    success: function(pushResponse) {
                        console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
                    },launch:"launch_url"
                });
```

The notification appears but clicking on it doesnt do anything.What i am doing wrong here.

Comment: not sure if it's just a typo/cut-and-paste error from your code, but your *if* statement has "lauchstring" not "launchstring".  Also, I presume that you're not using the literal "launch_url" in the argument within the mobile services script?

Comment: thanks. it was a typo that was causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding as answer given OP's confirmation of my comment*

It looks as there's a typo in your code, missing the first "n" in launchstring in the if condition:

```
string launchstring = args.Arguments;
if (lauchstring=="InstructionSet")
```